# Emacs: Format a long code line into multiple more readable lines

Tags: emacs

I have a long function call like this:

```
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

I would like to format it as:

```
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                            SCREEN_WIDTH, 
                            SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
                            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

I don't want to format the entire file like this, just specific lines as i write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the point on the open parenthesis (or just before it), then type:
C-M-space
M-% , RET , C-q C-j RET !
Put again the point on the open parenthesis (or just before it), then type:
C-M-q